# JDBC execute SQL Server stored procedure with return value and input/output parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure that takes 1 input value, 2 output parameters and also returns a value on execution

Over the internet i saw references using Call

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call ? = spName(?, ?, ?)}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.setObject(2, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NVARCHAR);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.NVARCHAR);
```

But this gives me the error

```
"Incorrect syntax near '{'"
```

Then i decided to do like the SQL Management Studio generated SQL code:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("exec ? = spName ?, ?, ?");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.setObject(2, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NVARCHAR);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.NVARCHAR);
```

But this gives me the error

```
"Incorrect syntax near '='"
```

I think this is because the query gets transformed to

```
"exec @P1 OUT = spName @P2, @P3 OUT, @P4 OUT"
```

and it doesn't work either on SQL Management Studio because 'OUT' appers before '='

And this leaves me without ideas because it doesn't work either way.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: That should be `{?=call spName(?, ?, ?)}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for calling a stored procedure is:

```
{[?=]call procedure-name[([parameter][,[parameter]]...)]}
```

So your first example triggers an exception in the parser of the JDBC call-escape because you put `call` before the return value. I am not sure about the problem with the second one.

So I would expect it to work if you modify your first example to:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{?=call spName(?, ?, ?)}");
```

You can find more information specifically for the Microsoft JDBC driver on MSDN:

- [Using Statements with Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378046.aspx)
- [Using a Stored Procedure with a Return Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378371.aspx)
- [Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx)

Comment: You're right! It's "?=call" and not "call ?=". How stupid of me :-)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also, for stored procedures without any arguments, it would just look like...

```
this.connection.prepareCall("{call dbo.storedProcedure()}")
```