# Stored Procedure with return values

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure "test", which looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
@name varchar(32)  
AS
DECLARE 
        @login_status  TINYINT, 
    @syb_login   varchar(20),
        @syb_pass   varchar(20)
...
..     


BEGIN   
            SELECT @status = 0
            SELECT @login as login,
                   @pass as pass,
                   @status as status   
             RETURN 0 
        END
```

I need to pass a single input parameter "myName" as input parameter to this procedure and which in turn returns the login, pass and status as output (from only one record) parameters.

In JDBC, I tried to do like below:

```
 String query = "{call test(?,?,?)}";
    System.out.println(query);
    CallableStatement proc = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        proc = connection.prepareCall(query);
        proc.setString(1, "myName");

    proc.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    proc.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

    proc.execute();

    System.out.println(proc.getString(2));
```

This always gives the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SG: A CallableStatement did not return as many output parameters as the application had registered for it.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.handleSQLE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.nextResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.doGetOutValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ParamManager.getOutValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.getString(Unknown Source)
```

I tried with [JDBC execute SQL Server stored procedure with return value and input/output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834544/jdbc-execute-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-return-value-and-input-output-para),
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx but this didn't work.

Comment: Show the complete create statement for your procedure.

Comment: The in/out variables are declared in `CREATE PROCEDURE test <params> AS ...`. Show us the `<params>`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I have added the create statement

Comment: Your stored procedure only has one input (`@name`), and no output parameters. You can't register parameters when they don't exist. You either have to use the `ResultSet` produced by the stored procedure, or you have to rewrite the stored procedure so it does have output parameters.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways:

**1. Redefine your procedure** (recommended)

Output paramteres have to be declared when creating a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    @name varchar(32),           
    @login varchar(32) = null output,
    @pass varchar(32) = null output,
    @status int = -1 output
AS
BEGIN   
        SET @status = 0
        SELECT @login = logincolumn,
               @pass = passcolumn
        FROM usertable

END
```

Then you can use it with JDBC as follows:

```
String query = "{call test(?,?,?,?)}";
[...]
proc = connection.prepareCall(query);
proc.setString(1, "myName");
proc.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
proc.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
proc.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Note:

- You have to `set` or `select` into the declared variables to give them output
  values.
- Usually it isn't a good idea to pass passwords around

**2. Catch the results from multiple resultsets** (not recommended)

```
Connection con;
CallableStatement proc = null;
ResultSet rs;

String qry = "{call test(?)}";
proc = con.prepareCall(qry);
proc.setString(1, "name");
proc.executeQuery();

// first result set returning the status
rs = proc.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}

 // second result set returning login and pass
if (proc.getMoreResults()) {
    rs = proc.getResultSet();
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("login"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("pass"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean declaring the parameter names. Yes. I have done it already.. Just included the first and last statements of the proc. I have updated it now.

Comment: I can be sure the proc is working fine. I can directly hit and get the output. But, not from jdbc

Comment: Updated the solution to provide a way if you are not able to change the procedure.

Comment: Even if the proc is working fine when working on a console, it is not the way it should be used. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx